# How to treat a group of vertices as one in Sculpt mode?

Tags: sculpting, masking

I am very new to Blender, and very much learning.
As of right now, to get a feel for how Blender works, I just use premade models, that I try to edit (the base figure from DAZ Studio, namely).
I have figured out how to use masks to avoid accidentally modifying parts I don't want to, like teeth or eyes. The problem is, I consistently have troubles with "lumpy" areas (let's call those "moles").
To be more precise:
Here's a plane with a "mole".[image: A plane with a mole]
When trying to sculpt the area that contains that mole, the mole itself distorts. It usually ends up too wide, or flattened, or fusing weirdly into the rest of the mesh. Like so:[image: The same plane, once inflated]
Which is not what I want. I'd like that mole to keep (at least roughly) the same shape and diameter, regardless of what happens to the surface it is on. So of course, I tried using a mask, but then a new problem arises:[image: The inflated plane after masking the mole]
All of the vertices of the mole are locked in space, and therefore do not end up where they belong (on the surface of the modified plane).

My understanding is I am looking for a way to make a group of vertices behave as one, so that all vertices in that group move in space together, but never in relation to one another. That is to say, I'd like all of the mole to move as a whole when I grab it, to be displaced but not distorted when I sculpt its surroundings, and so on. How would that be achieved? Or perhaps is there another method that I am not aware of to avoid that issue?
I should also mention that I usually sculpt models exported from DAZ to export them back and create a morphs, which means that it is quite essential whatever solution I use does not modify the topology of the figure.

Thank you very much in advance.